# MavensMate: showing errors in affected classes (in the sidebar)

Tags: apex, mavensmate

Is it possible to configure MavensMate to show errors in a list of Apex classes in sidebar?

In Force.com IDE, if I modify the constructor in one class, red error icons appear near the names of affected classes, which are using this constructor. It's very handy, because you can fix the issue straight after it has raised.

However, I could not find this functionality in MavensMate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mavensmate is a Sublime Text Plugin that **does not have the same functionalities** than Force.com IDE (but most of them). However, you will find many new cool features that doesn't exist on Force.com IDE.

Since It is Open Source you could [extend it and create that new feature](http://mavensmate.com/Getting_Started/Developers) (useful indeed). Check the plugin source on [github](https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate)

Otherwise, you could create your new feature request [here](https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate/issues) and wait for the community to have it.